# Eager Loading multiple rails associations with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, eager-loading

I am attempting to cut down on n+1 queries that are slowing things down. In this example I have three models clients, addresses, and contacts:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses, as: :addressable
  has_many :contacts
end

class Addresses < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
end

class Contacts < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :clients
end
```

Here the addresses table is polymporphic while the contacts - clients association is a one-to-many.  The addresses and contacts models each have a boolean attribute is_primary.

What I am wanting to do is have a clients index page that has a table showing the clients name, primary contact, and primary address.  The following sql query achieves this but I want to know how best to do this with ActiveRecord.

```
SELECT clients.id, clients.name, contacts.first_name,
contacts.last_name, addresses.city, addresses.state, 
addresses.country
FROM clients 
INNER JOIN contacts ON contacts.client_id = clients.id
INNER JOIN addresses ON addresses.addressable_id = clients.id
WHERE contacts.is_primary = TRUE AND addresses.is_primary = TRUE 
AND addresses.addressable_type = 'Client'
```

Any help would be greatly appreicated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@clients = Client.includes([:contacts, :addresses]).where(some_parameters)
```

Then in your view you can reference the relationships as normal without touching the database again since the tables have been loaded into memory via the includes method.

For conditionals this will help:

```
Client.includes([:contacts, :addresses]).where('contact.name = ?', 'example').references(:contacts)
```